# :'<,'> normal . doesn't work in vscode with vim plugin. How do i fix this?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, vim-plugin

> Run Normal Mode Commands Across a Range

If i want to put semicolon at the end of each line (example) , I do `A;` at one line and use `j.` (j , then dot ) to apply the same semicolon after each line. Instead of that I can select all those lines and do `:'<,'>normal .` in vim.

This doesn't seem to work in `vim plugin` on vscode. How do I get this functionality ? Any fix or config ?

Comment: just use the multi cursor of VSC

Comment: You might want to try neovim extension instead of vim extension for vscode. norm command works

Answer (score 0):

vim plugins won't have all of vim's functionality; vim is complicated. However, there is a simpler way to write that.

```
:'<,'>s/$/;/g
```

Is more basic syntax, to search and replace on each line, find the end of the line, and "replace" it with a `;`. While I don't have vscode, this syntax does work on the IntelliJ vim plugin.